# How to write routes for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have mvc project. In controllers I created folder Users. In this folder I put user controllers. So. What I need write on RouteConfig.cs file, that I manually on browser can open page of user controllers?
[image]

P.S. I wrote this way, but it didn't help me.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Users",
            "Users/AprilNelsonController/{action}",
            new { controller = "AprilNelsonController", action = "Index" },
            new[] { "Users" }
        );
```

Comment: you may refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178688/controller-in-sub-folder

Comment: Are you really going to create a controller for each person?

Comment: [MvcCodeRouting](https://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment card_master has provided should help you but I can see two main issues with your route config. Firstly you are including the word "controller" in the route. This is added by convention so MVC is probably looking for "AprilNelsonControllerController".

Secondly the namespace constraint needs to have the full namespace. e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Users",
    url: "Users/AprilNelson/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AprilNelson" action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "YourAppName.Controllers.Users" }
);
```

Which will enable the following route: "/Users/AprilNelson" or "/Users/AprilNelson/Index" to call the index action on the AprilNelsonController.

This can be further improved by removing the controller all together.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Users",
    url: "Users/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "YourAppName.Controllers.Users" }
);
```

This will allow you to call actions on any user in the same way e.g.

/Users/JessicaCox

/Users/SaraGreen

One thing to note is that you must put this route definition above your default route definition to ensure it get evaluated first.

Hope that helps.