# ASP.Net MVC Core routing to controllers which is in sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC core application which I have organized my codes to sub folders see attached image of my controller folder
how can I route to controllers in sub folders
[image]

View link:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Compensations" asp-action="Index">Compensation</a>
```

I did the following but didn't work for me

```
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
             //routes.MapRoute(
             //    name: "Statics",
             //    template: "{controller=Statics/Compensations}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

by default when I click on link i get bellow error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. 
The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

MJPractice.Controllers.CompensationsController.Index (MJPractice)
MJPractice.Controllers.Statics.CompensationsController.Index (MJPractice)
```

I checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx

and 
here: [Controller in Sub Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178688/controller-in-sub-folder) 
but didn't worked

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have two CompensationsController.cs files? What is the difference between them?

Comment: change the name to read `StaticCompensationsController`.

Comment: No it is only one controller but I don't know it calls two time one time without its sub folder and another time with its subfolder

Comment: You should not have two controllers with the same name. Can you rename one of them?